# Derivability conditions for Robinson arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic, reference-request, proof-theory

Two pieces of hearsay I have encountered about Robinson's Q:

1. Q fails to satisfy the Löb derivability conditions;
2. Pudlák criticised the Löb derivability conditions and suggested rival, weaker conditions.

Which leads to three questions, if the above are right:

1. Which derivability condition(s) does Q not satisfy;
2. What were Pudlák's rival conditions and what was his complaint with the Löb conditions; and
3. Does Q satisfy the rival conditions?

These questions arose from Carl Mummert's answer to a math.sx question of mine, [Can Robinson's Q prove Presburger arithmetic consistent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648/can-robinsons-q-prove-presburger-arithmetic-consistent).

Comment: I can take blame for passing along part (1) of the hearsay. When I went back to look for where I had seen it, I found published claims that Q is "too weak" to prove the derivability conditions, but not an explicit example nor a reference. Perhaps those authors were only referring to the fact that the usual proofs of the derivability conditions don't go through in Q, and I read too much into their statements. So I'm also interested to learn whether there is a published counterexample to the provability of the derivability conditions in Q. 

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but it was at least too long for a comment.

First, note than one can interpret Sam Buss's bounded arithmetic theories like $S^1_2$ in $Q$, so it is not as weak as it seems at first sight in expressing and proving theorems. One can use a reasonable formula to exclude those non-standard numbers which are too pathological and prove consistency of $L$ (if $S^1_2$ proves consistency of $L$).

I am not sure but you might find Pudlak's criticism in the last part of [Hajek and Pudlak](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Metamathematics-of-First-Order-Arithmetic/chapter/Miscellaneous-Frontmatter/pl/1235421927), and his alternative condition that you are looking for might be "sequential theory". Also take a look at [this article](https://www.math.cas.cz/%7Epudlak/consis.ps) which cites the Bezboruah et al. 1976 paper.

(By the way, Bezboruah et al. (1976) seems to be a decade before Nelson's Predicative Arithmetic (1986) which shows that one can interpret $I\Delta_0$ in Q.)